# How to fix gradient inside UIView()

Tags: swift, uikit

I can't see quizLineView on my VC, but when I just apply bakgroundcolor = .blue.
I can see quizLineView on my VC with blue color.

How to fix it, I need my quizLineView with gradient and proper corner radius?

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.examBackgroundLightScreen2()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setupTickMarks()
}

private func setupTickMarks() {
    
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = quizLineView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 39/255, green: 151/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 101/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    
    quizLineView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    quizLineView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    quizLineView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    
    addSubview(quizLineView)
    quizLineWidthConstraint = quizLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bounds.width - 24)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        quizLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 35),
        quizLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 6),
        quizLineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
        quizLineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor,constant: 12),
        quizLineWidthConstraint,
    ])
}
```

Comment: You may try to add quizLineView as subview to another view. Apply corner cornerRadius and gradientLayer to that view. quizLineView background should be clear then.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a few things differently...

- during initialization:

  - configure the gradient layer
  - add it as a sublayer to quizLineView
  - add the quizLineView as a subview of "self"
  - set the constraints for quizLineView
- in `layoutSubviews()`:

  - update the gradient layer frame
  - do anything else that depends on layout changes (I'm guessing you will be "adding tick marks"?)

So:

```
class QuizView: UIView {
    
    let quizLineView = UIView()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        // I don't have your color definition
        //backgroundColor = UIColor.examBackgroundLightScreen2()
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        // gradient properties
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 39/255, green: 151/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 101/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

        quizLineView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        quizLineView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        // add gradient layer to quizLineView
        quizLineView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        // use auto-layout constraints
        quizLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // add quizLineView
        addSubview(quizLineView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            quizLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 35),
            quizLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 6),
            quizLineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            quizLineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor,constant: 12),
        ])

    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupTickMarks()
    }
    
    private func setupTickMarks() {
        // update gradient layer frame
        gradientLayer.frame = quizLineView.bounds
    }
    
}
```

and a simple view controller to show it:

```
class QuizVC: UIViewController {
    let quizView = QuizView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        quizView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(quizView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            quizView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            quizView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            quizView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            quizView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that it will handle frame size changes, such as on device rotation, without any additional code:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a litle bit different but you can simulate as you wish for your project.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
  lazy var containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
  }()
    
  lazy var quizLineView: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.text = "Hello World!"
    return view
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    setupTickMarks()
  }


  private func setupTickMarks() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds // this shoukd be super view's bound
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 39/255, green: 151/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 101/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    containerView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    ])

    containerView.addSubview(quizLineView)
    quizLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      quizLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
      quizLineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
      quizLineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
      quizLineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    ])
  }
}
```

[image]